# Python take drop (exercise)

Tags: python

I was doing online course on python.
Chapter about "take drop" left 2 examples:

```
def take(num, lyst):
    rlist = []
    for i in range(0,num):
        rlist.append(lyst[i])
    return rlist

def drop(num, lyst):
     rlist = []
     for i in range(num, len(lyst)):
         rlist.append(lyst[i])
     return rlist

names = ['Raymond','Cynthia','David','Jennifer','Clayton']
somenames = take(3,names)
print(somenames)
names = drop(3,names)
print(names)
```

As an exercise i had to rewrite code so it would work with negative arguments as numbers (-3).

i came up with this code:

```
def take(num,lyst):
    rlist=[]
    if num>0:
        for i in range(0,num):
            rlist.append(lyst[i])
    else:
        for i in range(len(lyst)-abs(num),len(lyst)):
            rlist.append(lyst[i])
    return rlist

def drop(num,lyst):
    rlist=[]
    if num>0:
        for i in range(num,len(lyst)):
            rlist.append(lyst[i])
        return rlist
    else:
        for i in range(len(lyst)-abs(num),len(lyst)):
            rlist.append(lyst[i])
        return rlist
```

But I think its not efficient enough what would be better suggestion.
Edit: modified functions should work backwards too.example: take(-3,names) would take 3 from last

Comment: So, what would be the results of `take(-3, names)` and `drop(-3, names)`? Is your code already producing the right result?

Comment: modified functions should work backwards too.example: take(-3,names) would take 3 from last, which worked, but was looking for better code for this

Comment: *"i think its not efficient enough"* - on what basis? Is there some performance problem (memory? CPU? Have you profiled it?) Could you expand on your criteria for efficiency? If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com, but I suggest you read and follow [the style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as a first port of call.

Answer (score 2):

Performance-wise, your code should be fine, as it does only one pass through the list in any case. If you are looking for a cleaner or more elegant way, I have two suggestions:

- use list-comprehensions instead of loops
- define the "negative" case of `drop` in terms of `take` and vice versa

Example for `take`:

```
def take(num, lst):
    if num > 0:
        return [lst[i] for i in range(0, min(num, len(lst)))]
    else:
        return drop(max(len(lst) + num, 0), lst)
```

The inverse, `drop`, is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

`take` and `drop` are typically used together to get a slice, and for that you can use `itertools.islice` directly, but you still can define `take` and `drop` in term of `islice`:

```py
from itertools import islice

def take(count, it): 
    return islice(it, count)

def drop(count, it): 
    return islice(it, count, None)
```

Using it like so:

```py
>>> from itertools import count
>>> mylist = list(take(10, drop(100, count())))
>>> mylist
[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
```

---

In the context of your question, however, it make no sense to use `islice` because an iterator might not have the notion of *end*. For example you can't drop 3 items from the end of `itertoos.cycle("abcd")`.

But since you are limiting your question to lists, a list has the slice operations: `mylist[start:stop:step]`

```py
def take_list(count, lst):
    return lst[:count]

def drop_list(count, lst):
    return lst[count:]
```

Using it:

```py
>>> take_list(3, mylist)
[100, 101, 102]
>>> drop_list(3, mylist)
[103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
```

---

But in this definition `take_list(-3, "abcdefg")` does what you wnat `drop_list(-3, "abcdefg")` so:

```py
def neg_take_list(count, lst):
    return lst[count:] if count < 0 else lst[:count]

def neg_drop_list(count, lst):
    return lst[:count] if count < 0 else lst[count:]
```

and now for negative `count` you we get:

```py
>>> neg_take_list(-3, mylist)
[107, 108, 109]
>>> neg_drop_list(-3, mylist)
[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106]
```

---

If you intend to have `take` and `drop` giving you the items in reverse order you can use a `step` of `-1`:
(Note an off by one issue that we need to address by decrementing a negative `count`)

```py
def rev_take_list(count, lst):
    return lst[:count-1:-1] if count < 0 else lst[:count]

def rev_drop_list(count, lst):
    return lst[count-1::-1] if count < 0 else lst[count:]
```

Note an off-by-one issue that we need to address by decrementing the negative `count`.

Here in with negative `count` we get:

```py
>>> rev_take_list(-3, mylist)
[109, 108, 107]
>>> rev_drop_list(-3, mylist)
[106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100]
```